# getopts Unix input

Tags: shell-script, getopts

so in my code below I'm like trying to get my code to read the input that the user enters in my code as seen below

```
#./MyProject -a -b OR -b -a
```

However I keep getting a Syntax error and its not passing the tests given by the program: The following tests are: having inputs that aren't a&b (i.e c-z), having no inputs at all, having too little arguments, having too many arguments,

```
#Use just prints out the format like this : ./MyProject -a -b

 - if ( ! getopts ":ab" arg) then  
echo $use  
fi 

 while [getopts ":ab" arg2] 
do
         case $arg2 in

        t) if (($1 != "t" && $1 != "o")); then
         echo $use 
     fi   
 esac   
done  
}
```

Comment: Sorry everyone I've been having a hard time trying to convert my code into the coding here.... I don't know how to format it correctly...

Answer (score 4):

The following example should work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 -a -b"
    exit
}

while getopts ":a:b:" arg; do
    case $arg in
        a)
            a=${OPTARG}
            (($a == "t" || $a == "o")) || usage
            ;;
        b)
            b=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done

echo $a
echo $b
```

Comment: Thank you so much daisy for answering so quickly, Do you know tho about having too little arguments?

Comment: too little or none :) if you can let me know i'll appreciate it!

Comment: @Bob you can check arguments using `if (($# < 2 )); then usage; fi`.

Comment: Thanks and if there was an extra argument after the list? I tried if (($# > 3 )); then usage; fi but it didn't work

Comment: extra argument (not beeing -a/-b will be caught by *) in case.

Comment: that's what it thought but it isn't being caught by the *) case.

Comment: it works if i add this code     if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then it just fails the rest of the other code that daisy provided.